# Is there a way to open a new version of Chrome, without Selenium

Tags: google-chrome

When starting Chrome with Selenium, it opens up a new version of the browser.
No history, no bookmarks and default settings as if it just got installed.

**Is there a way to open a new version of Chrome like Selenium does, without using Selenium?**
I already know about incognito mode or profiles. I searched online but can't anything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question has nothing to do with selenium or python. remove the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way,
On the top right corner beside the kebab menu click on the profile pic. Then click on Guest option in the bottom of the drop down menu. It will open a fresh profile for you to use.

[image: Guest user]

You can open chrome with different profile using command line switch. But you have to specify the directory and if you use the same directory it will use the same profile. Change the directory from the following to your liking.

`start chrome --user-data-dir=C:\tempdir\`